# django blocktrans and with tag - DRY approach

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I create a DRY approach with the following code segment?

This may be an easy question, but it has me stumped.

I have tried for the past two days, but I cannot figure out how to have just the one blocktrans while incorporating the django with tag.

Here is my template tag code:

```
{% if user.userprofile.subscription_category == subscription_type_free %}
    {% with temp_max_language_versions=max_language_versions_free_subscription %}
        {% blocktrans %}You have the ability to create <strong>{{ temp_max_language_versions }}</strong> different {{ resume_details_tran }} with your <a href="{{ user_account_details }}">subscription</a>.{% endblocktrans %}
    {% endwith %}

{% elif user.userprofile.subscription_category == subscription_type_03 %}
    {% with temp_max_language_versions=max_language_versions_level03_subscription %}
    {% blocktrans %}You have the ability to create <strong>{{ temp_max_language_versions }}</strong> different {{ resume_details_tran }} with your <a href="{{ user_account_details }}">subscription</a>.{% endblocktrans %}
    {% endwith %}

{% elif user.userprofile.subscription_category == subscription_type_06 %}
    {% with temp_max_language_versions=max_language_versions_level06_subscription %}
        {% blocktrans %}You have the ability to create <strong>{{ temp_max_language_versions }}</strong> different {{ resume_details_tran }} with your <a href="{{ user_account_details }}">subscription</a>.{% endblocktrans %}
    {% endwith %}

{% elif user.userprofile.subscription_category == subscription_type_12 %}
   {% with temp_max_language_versions=max_language_versions_level12_subscription %}
       {% blocktrans %}You have the ability to create <strong>{{ temp_max_language_versions }}</strong> different {{ resume_details_tran }} with your <a href="{{ user_account_details }}">subscription</a>.{% endblocktrans %}
   {% endwith %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is always the same with a different temp_max_language_versions variable. Three ways around this:

1 - use an include:

```
{% if user.userprofile.subscription_category == subscription_type_free %}
    {% include 'path_to_include.html' with  temp_max_language_versions=max_language_versions_free_subscription %}
{% elif user.userprofile.subscription_category == subscription_type_03 %}
....
```

2 - OR you could add that to the category itself; some pseudo-code:

```
class SubscriptionCategory(...):

    @property
    def temp_max_language_versions(self):
         if self.type == 'something':
              return 'something_else'
```

3 - if it's specific to the view, you could add that to the category via the view as well.

Comment: Thanks François - I used the include.